# How to show this function is surjective

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

$T(x,y,z) = (2x + y + 3z, 3y - 4z, 5x)$ for $R^3 \rightarrow R^3$

I read the meaning of surjective over and over, but I don't understand how to show it algebraically. So I just guessed:

$2x + y + 3z = a \\
3y - 4z = b \\
5x = c$

So $x = \frac{c}{5}$. Then we have $\frac{2c}{5} + y + 3z = a$ and $3y - 4z = b$

I'm lost here. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do, but I just guessed and and trying to express things in other variables. I'm not sure what I am doing.

Comment: What is the codomain? It's fundamental for the surjectivity. For example $\sin:\mathbb R\rightarrow[-1,1]$ is surjective, but $\sin:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ not!

Comment: @Joe I think It's $R^3 \rightarrow R^3$. The book says $R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ but it might be a typo

Comment: You're doing it correctly, just finish. Keep your goal in mind: given $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb R^3$, you need to show there is a point $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$ with $T(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)$. This is just a system of 3 equations in 3 unknowns (remember, you should regard $a$, $b$, and $c$ as given constants). You've already solved for $x$, so use its value in the remaining pair of equations to solve for $y$ and $z$. So, for example, use one of them to write $y$ in terms of $z$ (and the known value of $x$) and substitute it into the other to solve for $z$. Then get $y$ since you now know everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $\frac{2c}{5}+y+3z=a$ and $3y-4z=b$ you just have to solve a linear system. The idea is to get $y,z$ in terms of $a,b,c$.

The second equation gives you $y=\frac{4z+b}{3}$, replacing in the first equation you get $\frac{2c}{5}+\frac{4z+b}{3}+3z=a$, therefore $z=\frac{15a-5b-6c}{65}$. Now you take this value of $z$ and replace in $y=\frac{4z+b}{3}$, then you have that $y = \frac{20a+15b-8c}{65}$.

I didn't show all the calculations, check this out to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

As you have been told, solving for $x,y,z$ is always a way to prove surjectivity. But in this concrete case, there is a shorter way.

Note that $T$ is a linear function, so you can express it with a matrix:

$$T\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{rrr}2&1&3\\0&3&-4\\5&0&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z\end{array}\right)$$

Since the determinant of the matrix is $5(-4-9)\neq0$, the rank of $T$ is $3$ and hence $T$ is surjective.